# Oracle Database error Error(3,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: language

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle SQL, I try to write a new package.
However I get this error, after searching solutions from this site, I still don't understand what the error is.
Please help me to solve the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error(5,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657775/error5-3-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-begin-when-expecting-one-of-the)

Comment: @defaultlocale I know thousand of questions about this error had been posted, but I still dont understand in my situation

Comment: You need to place a procedure implementation (begin-end part) in the package *body*. Please, read the answer in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657775/error5-3-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-begin-when-expecting-one-of-the#10657814

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are attempting to crate a PACKAGE header and include in it the body of your procedure.

Packages have HEADER (or specification) and BODY. The header only includes signatures of the procedures/functions/types/variables that you want to make accessible from the outside world (of the package).

The body includes, among other things, the implementation of the procedures/functions.

To resolve your problem, leave within the package header only the specification of the procedure and put the details within the package body.

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: When I seperate the HEADER and BODY, I get the error 'Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" '

Comment: Which tool are you using? SQL Developer?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: OK. The "/" is used by SQL Developer as an indication of "END OF BLOCK". I also had issues with it so turned to work differently: Within SQL Developer, you can right-click and "Create Package" or "Create Package Body". This is the safest way. Remember: FIRST Specifications, then BODY, in that order. Good luck!!!

Comment: Actually, from what I remember, you are allowed to define the package body first, and the the header, you'd just probably have to recompile (or execute), to have the body validated, as it'd get created as invalid and would not validate automatically when the specification is put in place.

Comment: @Hilarion, I don't think so but, really, it is no so important.

Comment: @FDavidov: I've tested it with Oracle Live SQL, and it seems you are right. Thank you for the clarification and sorry for introducing unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As @FDavidov mentioned you need

a `package specification` part

and

have to keep your current code in `package body` part starting with

`create or replace package body MONITORFLUSSI as ...`

The Place you get the errors may be confusing in Oracle sometimes. The error you get because of missing `body` keyword between `create or replace package` and `MONITORFLUSSI as` on the first line. After adding `body` there, you'll get

> Error(1,14): PLS-00201: identifier 'MONITORFLUSSI' must be declared
>
> Error(1,14): PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'MONITORFLUSSI'
>   without its specification

Then create a `specification part` besides `body part` of the package and

in the `body part` you need to return your column values' to some variable(s)

by means of `INTO Clause` or a `Cursor` :

```
create or replace package MONITORFLUSSI as
  procedure get_monitorflussi(dataSegnalazione in date, compagnia in varchar2, tabella in varchar2, daInviare in number, o_tabella out varchar2 );
  procedure get_monitorflussi(daInviare in number, o_tabella out varchar2 );
end MONITORFLUSSI;


create or replace package body MONITORFLUSSI as
  procedure get_monitorflussi(dataSegnalazione in date, compagnia in varchar2, tabella in varchar2, daInviare in number, o_tabella out varchar2 ) is
  begin
    for c in ( select * from monitor_flussi t where t.daInviare = daInviare )
    loop
      o_tabella := c.tabella;
    end loop;   
  end;

  procedure get_monitorflussi(daInviare in number, o_tabella out varchar2 ) is
  begin
    select t.tabella into o_tabella  from monitor_flussi t where t.daInviare = daInviare;
  end;
end MONITORFLUSSI;
```

In which, I've overridden the procedure `get_monitorflussi` for both cases

`INTO Clause` and `Cursor`.

Comment: I get the error 'Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" '

Comment: This should seperate into 2 package: one is normal package, one is package body

Comment: @anhtv13 if you use Worksheet instead of command line, no need to use a slash.